# Tereo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface Code 10 error

Tags: graphics-card

not sure I'm in the right place but I'm going to ask and hope for the best.

I've got a ~6 month old Asus K60IJ Series notebook running 64-bit Windows 7.
Processor - Pentium Dual Core CPU T4400 2.20 GHz
RAM - 4GB
Hard Drive - 451GB with 402GB free
Internet Provider - Verizon Fios
I connect wirelessly

Having several problems, actually.

1. Can't install MS Office 2010. Get error message that my system's language isn't the same as the install. No biggie, I'll figure it out eventually.
2. There's a vertical line showing up on the LCD monitor. Right in the middle. It's white. My son was on the computer today and said it just showed up. I don't believe him but not sure how much I'll get out of a 7yo.
3. While looking around the system for something to give me a clue to if the line is the video card going bad already, I found an error message related to the "Tereo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface network adapter: "This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

I understand this thing has something to do with IPV6 being on my computer and IPV4 being what's available from our internet provider...I know they're something to do with network speed but that's the extent of my knowledge. Just headline definitions.

The driver is up to date. I just uninstalled the driver and planned to re-install but now I can't find the thing. Is it even necessary?

Thank you!

Comment: None of these three issues seem related. You should post each individual issue as its own topic.